# Mockito mocking with Enum parameter not working

Tags: mockito, powermock

I can't figure out what is wrong with this, hopefully someone can help:

I have an enum, MyEnum that is used as a parameter to a method I am trying to mock. The mocking looks a bit like this:

```
when(myMockedObject.getMethod(MyEnum.XYZ)).thenReturn(myMockedValue);
```

and the actual code execution looks like this:

```
MyMockedValue theMockedValue = myMockedObject.getMethod(MyEnum.XYZ);
```

I'm expecting theMockedValue to equal myMockedValue. However, the mocking is not working and theMockedValue is always null. What is wrong with this?

Comment: That should work. Could you show more code (the enum, test, tested) ?

Comment: @Brice - As is so often the case I have found the problem is down to my dodgy code! the mocking does work, as you suggest it should. The problem was that I had a bug in my test where I had two mocked instances of myMockedObject. I set one up to return a mocked value and then erroneously used the other one in the code. Once the duplicate mock was removed it all worked fine. Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was down to my own dodgy code. I found a duplicated mock object, one instance was involved in the mocking and the other was being used in the code, resulting in null values being returned.

Just as I thought I was losing the battle with mockito and now I realise I do understand what is going on.